# Javascript Nested Functions Using Combination of Reduce, Map and Concat with an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

Can someone please explain to me how this code:

```
const powerset = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => a.concat(a.map(r => [v].concat(r))), [[]]);
console.log(powerset(["dog", "pig"]));
```

returns this array output in the console?

```
0: []
1: ["dog"]
2: ["pig"]
3: (2) ["pig", "dog"]
length: 4
```

The point was to take the elements from an array and return all of the possible combinations of those elements. I understand the reduce function, concatenating and mapping, but I'm having a hard time comprehending how these nested functions are being applied and in what order to get this output. Anyone able to walk me through what is happening on each run-through of the function(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to view the code as separate functions:

```js
function powerset(arr) {
  const initial = [[]];
  return arr.reduce(reduceFn, initial);

  function reduceFn(accumulatedValue, item) {
    // item will be "dog" or "pig"
    // accumulatedValue will start as [[]] and be equal to the result of the previous call of reduceFn by .reduce()
    const concatenatedAccumulation = accumulatedValue.map(function mapFn(e) {
      return [item].concat(e) // i.e. [item, ...e]
    });
    return accumulatedValue.concat(concatenatedAccumulation);
  }
}
```

The execution of `arr.reduce` looks like this (read as `call(): result`):

1. `reduceFn(accumulatedValue = [[]], item = 'dog'): [[], ['dog']]`

   - accumulatedValue.map: `mapFn(e = []): [['dog']]`

     - return [item].concat: `['dog'].concat([]): ['dog']`
   - return accumulatedValue.concat: `return [[]].concat([['pig']])`
2. `reduceFn(accumulatedValue = [[], ['dog']], item = 'pig'): [[], ['dog'], ['pig'], ['pig', 'dog']]`

   - accumulatedValue.map: `mapFn(e = [[], ['dog']]): [['pig'], ['pig', 'dog']]`

     - return [item].concat: `['pig'].concat([]): ['pig']`
     - return [item].concat: `['pig'].concat(['dog']): ['pig', 'dog']`
   - return accumulatedValue.concat: `return [[], ['dog']].concat([['pig'], ['pig', 'dog']])`

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! It took me a while of staring at your answer but it finally clicked, and I was able to apply your logic to my original one-line function to understand how it's working. Seriously appreciate your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, take the constant and turn it into a function:

```
function powerset(arr){
  return arr.reduce((a, v) => a.concat(a.map(r => [v].concat(r))), [[]])
}
```

We know that `reduce` will loop through the elements and put them into `a`, the accumulator. Meanwhile, it will also do 'something' with `v`, the value. So, let's dig deeper:

`a.concat(a.map(r => [v].concat(r)))`

Here, it takes the accumulator and adds an array to it. But what is the array? This is:

`a.map(r => [v].concat(r))`

Now we can see that it takes each element of `a` and essentially pushes `v`, the value, into it.

Working backwards, now we can see that `a` starts off as `[[]]`, then gets merged with the array that is outputted from `a.map(r => [v].concat(r))`. That simply happens to be the first element of `arr`. So, it turns to `[[], [first_element]]`.

Repeating this, we can see that each time, it takes an element, adds it to each subarray in the accumulator, takes all of those arrays, and adds it back to the accumulator. So now, you have all sets both with the example element `el`, AND without the example element `el`. Repeating, you have all possible combinations.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! I'm close to understanding now but can't get past one thing. When we do the first map-through, when the initial value of `a` is just the empty set of brackets `[[]]` and `v` is the value `"dog"`, when we run through `a.map(r => [v].concat(r))`, would the resulting array be `[[dog],[]]`, `[dog, []]`or simply just `[dog]`? I'm just wondering if you try to concatenate an empty array to a value like "dog", if it will not recognize the empty array at all or if it will concatenate the empty brackets.

Comment: `[[]].map(r => ['dog'].concat(r))` (v = "dog") would result in `[['dog']]` because you are concatenating on an empty array (`r`).

Comment: Ok, just what I was thinking! So in this case, when we run through the map the first time, we simply get `["dog"]`. Why then, when we do `a.concat( ["dog"] )`, does the console successfully bring back `[ [], ["dog"] ]`, if an empty array cannot be concatenated to anything? Or, is the case that you can concatenate a value to an empty array, but you cannot concatenate an empty array to a value?

Comment: `[[]]` is not an empty array. It is an array with an empty sub-array. So, it just adds `["dog"]` to it while concating, resulting in `[[], ["dog"]]`

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Answered! Here was the original code, along with my new understanding of what's going on:

```
const powerset = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => a.concat(a.map(r => [v].concat(r))), [[]]);
console.log(powerset(["dog", "pig"]));
```

1.) The reduce function is taking in the accumulator `a`, which starts with our initializer `[[]]`, and the first value `v` from the array `powerset`, which is `dog`.

2.) When we map through `a`, our first value of `r` is the empty array with subarray, `[[]]`. When you do `[dog].concat([[]])`, you end up with just `[dog]`.

3.) Then, you have `a.concat(dog)`, so you end up with `[[], [dog]]`. Your new accumulator or `a` value is now `[[], [dog]]`.

4.) Next loop of the reduce function, accumulator `a` is `[[], [dog]]`, and `v` is the second item in our `powerset` array, `pig`.

5.) Again, map through `a`. First loop will be `pig.concat([])`. You will just get `[pig]`.

6.) Next loop will be `pig.concat([dog])`, so you get `[pig, dog]`.

7.) Now, perform the `a.concat` again. Because our new `a` was `[[], [dog]]`, we are now adding our two new results to get `[[], [dog], [pig], [pig, dog]]`.

That is how we end up with all of the different combinations of "pig, dog".